# How to start Backtrack after installation

Tags: boot, backtrack

I am having xp and ubuntu installed in my sytem. Then I installed Backtrack5R1 but after reboot with the grub entry of Backtrack(Updated grub from ubuntu) leads to the same state that was before installation of backtrack as with install icon in the desktop.

How the installation is lost in the way and every time I install I didn't find it in the same state but only install icon in the desktop for backtrack.

Any help would be really helping.

Comment: Not really sure what that means, do you have any diagnostics/screens/additional details?

Comment: @jmreicha I meant to say that when we first time start linux in live mode the screen which we get showing the install icon in the workspace  is shown to me even if I finish installing BackTrack and reboot again I get the same workspace with install icon in it.   I wonder where did my installation went. After this scenario I started Ubuntu and updated the grub which added the entry for Backtrack in the grub but when i start from there I receive the same workspace with install icon in it.  I am installing in a partition so I could not generate any screenshots for it.

Comment: So can you tell if the backtrack installation was successful by looking at the partition structure?  Either with an 'fdisk -l' from command line or from a gparted Live CD?

Comment: @jmreicha Before installing the OS I made all the partitions beforehand.The partitions made for LINUX are not visible in XP. While from Ubuntu I can see all the partitions available. During installation I selected EXT4 for Backtrack. All of the partitions are seperate for different OS.